# C# login issue in Visual Studio 2012 express

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Guys I am woking on a project and have some issues.
Its a basic login app writing to a local DB.
I know in terms of security its not right, but its for a proof of concept only.
It validates and loads up in my browser.
Then when I fill in the data I get the following error:

code line highlighted:    `int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());` 
error is as follows:

> SqlException was unhandled by user code
>
> Incorrect syntax near "Staff"

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class LoginPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ShowUsersConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string checkuser = "select count(*) form Staff where UserName='" + txtUserName.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString()); //
            conn.Close();


            if (temp == 1)
            {
                conn.Open();
                string CheckPassQuery = "select password from Staff where UserName='" + txtUserName.Text + "'";
                SqlCommand passcom = new SqlCommand(CheckPassQuery, conn);
                string password = passcom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                if (password == txtPassword.Text)
                {
                    Session["New"] = txtUserName.Text;
                    Response.Write("Password correct");
                    Response.Redirect("Users.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("Password is incorrect");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Username ivalid");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't do this.  This is classic "vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)" code.  Please use [parameterized queries](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/113/Preventing-SQL-Injection-in-ASP.NET) instead.

Comment: Did you even look at the SQL statement the error is referencing? If you did, you would have noticed you mis-spelled `from` as `form`.

Comment: I don't care if it is proof-of-concept, seeing `TextBox.Text` in a SQL query makes me so uneasy

Comment: As well as the other comments, I would strongly suggest that you don't store plain-text passwords in your database

Answer (score 5):

Here's your error:

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) form Staff where UserName='" + txtUserName.Text + "'";
```

`form` should be `from`

Also, look into [SQL Injection](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, i am well aware of sql injection, this is for really basic functionality. Once the site works I will fix issues identified. Thanks again

Comment: No problem, happy to help, if this answers your question, please [accept it as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It's still a good idea to mention the SQLi for the benefit of other users that don't know about it and find this question.